# Text to Columns feature finding second space

Tags: excel

You can split text on each space, can this be formatted to only effect the second space in each cell?

[image: Example]

I'm looking for an option that would not require VBA if possible.

Comment: I have edited the original question to include an example. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search command allows for a starting position to search from.
Since you want to find the second space you can start the search from after the second space by nesting two search statements.
Doing this with a formula can be done like this:

```
=LEFT(A1, SEARCH(" ", A1, SEARCH(" ", A1) + 1))

=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - (SEARCH(" ", A1, SEARCH(" ", A1) + 1)))
```

The part finding the second space being `SEARCH(" ", A1, SEARCH(" ", A1) + 1)`